# Load TGLImage or TGLTexture from stream

Tags: image, delphi, stream, glscene

I am using GLScene SVN Snapshot 6432 with Delphi XE2 and it does not seem to be possible load a texture image from a stream.

I have scanned through the documentation and searched the internet but all I can find
is the declaration LoadFromFile, no LoadFromStream is present anywhere.

I have looked through the sourcecode as well but I can not find or understand the code which handles
the file-loading process either.

Is it possible to somehow load an image-file from a TMemoryStream to a TGLTexture or TGLImage?

**EDIT:**

I did some more research:

There are indeed LoadFromStream declarations available and they seem to point to the file
ApplicationFileIO.pas located in the GLScene Source Directory.

When calling LoadFromStream from TGLImage, for instance, I get the error message
"Import for TGLImage to TMemoryStream not available. (C:\GLSeneLibraryPath\Source\ApplicationFileIO.pas, line 348)".

I have tried the following code when getting the message mentioned above:

```
procedure TtestForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var ms: tmemorystream;
      img: tglimage;
begin
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  img:=TGLImage.Create;

  opd.Execute(Self.Handle);

  ms.LoadFromFile(opd.FileName);
  img.LoadFromStream(ms);

  ms.Free;
  img.Free;
end;
```

Could it possibly be so that I need to somehow use the ApplicationFileIO.pas unit to get this working?

I have tried including that file in the uses clause everywhere but it does not make a difference.

Comment: Could you be more detailed, since in GLGraphics.pas `TGLImage = class(TGLBaseImage)` has a public `procedure LoadFromStream(stream: TStream); override;`

Comment: There are 63 procedures named `LoadFromStream` in the `source` directory of the files that I just downloaded.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question.

Comment: What version you are using? This error could only appear if LoadFromStream should not be implemented in your version, or if there is an other class named GLImage in your path. BTW. what you might try to achive (BMP/PNG) won't work this way, the way to go would be `img.Assign(bmp)` or `img.Assign(png)` with objects which could be loaded from a stream of course.

Comment: Sorry I never wrote what version. I am using Delphi XE2 and GLScene SVN Snapshot 6432

Comment: @bummi when adding the code var jpg: TPicture; begin ... jpg:=TPicture.Create; 
jpg.LoadFromFile(opd.FileName); 
img.Assign(jpg);... end; I get the error message "Cannot assignt TPicture to TGLImage"

Comment: @bummi however changing the jpg variable from jpg: TJPEGData; and using it accordingly I get no error message.

Comment: Sorry, I mean TJPEGImage, not TJPEGData.